# Preload data in TF

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue

I want to preload training data during training `CNN` in `TF` and my simple implementation is as follows. However, I find one strange phenomenon. It seems to be a synchronous process. The time cost for loading one batch data is almost same whether `PRE_FETCH` is `True` or `False`.

```
class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = 'demo'

    def load_batch(self):
        ...

    def prefetch(self, func):
        while True:
            data = func()
            self.queue.put(data)

    def train(self):
        input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[B, H, W, C])
        optim_op = build_model(input_data)

        if PRE_FETCH:
            self.queue = Queue(30)
            self.process = Process(target=self.prefetch, args=(self.load_batch))
            self.process.start()
            def cleanup():
                self.process.terminate()
                self.process.join()
            import atexit
            atexit.register(cleanup)
        sess = tf.Session()
        i = 1
        while i < MAX_ITER_SIZE:
            if PRE_FETCH:
                start = time.time()
                tmp = self.queue.get()
                end = time.time()
                print 'load data time: ', (end - start)
            else:
                start = time.time()
                tmp = self.load_batch()
                end = time.time()
                print 'load data time: ', (end - start)
            sess.run(optim_op, feed_dict={input_data: tmp}
```

Answer (score 0):

What takes time is loading your data into the graph through a placeholder. If you want your preloading to be effective, you should investigate replacing your python queue and thread mecanisme with tensorflow in-graph operations. There is a good tutorial on how to do this on the tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data